# How To Resolve Str_pad issue in php

Tags: php

I am trying to perform multiplication but i am unable to format with str_pad but i am unable to do in this format

for example if i am trying to multiply. 421 by 675

```
 I want to do exactly in this format

         4 2 1
      x  6 7 5
      __________
       2 1 0 5
     2 9 4 7 x
   2 5 2 6 x x
________________
   2 8 4 1 7 5
```

but there is a problem in padding i am unable to show these `x` in the str_pad it is not working properly  when i am using this format.
It is displaying like this

[image: padd]

this is the code

```
$multiplier = 421;
$multiplicand = 675;
$result = $multiplier * $multiplicand;
$pad_max = strlen($result);

$multiplicand_values = str_split($multiplicand);

echo str_pad($multiplier, $pad_max, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
echo "<br/>";
echo str_pad("x" . $multiplicand, $pad_max, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
echo "<br/>";
echo str_pad("-", $pad_max, "-", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
 echo "<br/>";

for($i = 0; null !== ($digit = array_pop($multiplicand_values)); ++$i)
{
    echo str_pad($multiplier * $digit * pow(1, $i), $pad_max, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<br/>";
}

 echo "<br/>";
echo str_pad("-", $pad_max, "-", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
echo "<br/>";
echo str_pad($result, $pad_max, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Browser are ignoring spaces in HTML if there are more than one. You need to use &nbsp; and monospace font. Or use `<pre>`

Comment: well i can doo with the css but it will not be responsive

Comment: Therefore it is only a comment;) But without that you will be not able to see if your code works or not.

Comment: @MichałSznurawa i have given a screenshot because i was having problem with the format

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try with [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$multiplier = 421;
$multiplicand = 675;
$result = $multiplier * $multiplicand;
$pad_max = strlen($result);

$multiplicand_values = str_split($multiplicand);

echo sprintf("%${pad_max}s", $multiplier)."<br/>";
echo sprintf("%${pad_max}s", "x".$multiplicand)."<br/>";
echo str_repeat("_", $pad_max)."<br/>";

for($i = 0; null !== ($digit = array_pop($multiplicand_values)); ++$i)
{
    $value = $multiplier * $digit * pow(1, $i);
    $xValue = str_repeat("x", $i);
    echo sprintf("%${pad_max}s", $value.$xValue)."<br/>";
}

echo str_repeat("_", $pad_max)."<br/>";
echo $result;
```

Result:

```
   421
  x675
______
  2105
 2947x
2526xx
______
284175
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/576822)

---

For getting this output:

```
      4 2 1
    x 6 7 5
___________
    2 1 0 5
  2 9 4 7 x
2 5 2 6 x x
___________
2 8 4 1 7 5
```

You need to split the words. I used [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php):

```
$multiplier = 421;
$multiplicand = 675;
$result = $multiplier * $multiplicand;
$pad_max = strlen(word_Wrap($result));

$multiplicand_values = str_split($multiplicand);

echo sprintf("%${pad_max}s", word_Wrap($multiplier))."<br/>";
echo sprintf("%${pad_max}s", word_Wrap("x".$multiplicand))."<br/>";
echo str_repeat("_", $pad_max)."<br/>";

for($i = 0; null !== ($digit = array_pop($multiplicand_values)); ++$i)
{
    $value = $multiplier * $digit * pow(1, $i);
    $xValue = str_repeat("x", $i);
    echo sprintf("%${pad_max}s", word_Wrap($value.$xValue))."<br/>";
}

echo str_repeat("_", $pad_max)."<br/>";
echo word_Wrap($result);

function word_Wrap($value) {
    return wordwrap($value, 1, " ", true);
}
```

Comment: i am posting a screen shot in the question again then you can see the problem

Comment: @thamilian the first line of the answer 2105 move to the right . I want to move on the left

Comment: please check the screenshot in the question @thamilan

Comment: @modgeek I get the format: [Demo 1](https://3v4l.org/MqbK0)  and  [Demo 2](https://eval.in/576959)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112929/discussion-between-mod-geek-and-thamilan).